# Group Policy Software Installation

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, msi

Is there a way when making a group policy object to install an MSI that you can have this install run as administrator on the computers?

Trying to run a fix that needs to be run as administrator to install.

Thank you.

Comment: You have setup a **Computer policy** right?  You aren't trying to deploy with a **User Policy**?

Comment: I have it under computer configuration, policies, software settings, software installation

Answer (score 2):

No. It runs as `SYSTEM` and this behavior cannot be changed. In almost all cases, this is plenty to install any piece of software.

Comment: Any suggestions to push something out then that needs to be installed on roughly 500 machines...

Comment: First of all, are you sure that running it as `SYSTEM` won't do what you need it to do?

Comment: I'm fairly new to this, and this is my first time setting up an MSI for installation for I'm not sure if I am running it as SYSTEM. How do I go about checking that?

Comment: You can test this by downloading a copy of psexec from the sysinternal tools and running `psexec -s msiexec /i c:\path\to\your\file.msi`. If it installs correctly this way, you can use GPO Software Deployment.